# TableView Auto Scrolling misbehaving after adding cells

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

### View Setup:

My TableView has 3 sections with 4 or 9 cell each. Each Cell has a Label and TextField.
On Starting to edit a cell at index 2 of each section, I reload the section which will now consist of 9 cells(update model to dequeueCell so that 5 more cells will be added).

### Problem:

The tableView scrolls as expected(brings textfield to visible part of the screen) for the unexpanded state of the section. But after I add cells by beginning to edit the textfield of cell at index 2 of any section, the tableView scrolls such that it hides the textfield. The weird scrolling occurs for any cells in the tableview once any section has expanded numbers of cells. Also, while weird scroll is happening, the tableView is reloaded(which is leading to lose the focus away from textfield). I have included `tableView.reloadSection(_:)` in the `didBeginEditing(:_)` custom delegate of the cell.
I have seen this problem in iOS 9 and 10

Sorry for poor explanation. Thanks

Heres the [Github Repo](https://github.com/sanjaymhj/WeirdScroll.git)

And Problem is here [image: Problem Demo]

P.S. I am using Swift 3 and Xcode 8.3.3 with deployment target iOS 10

Please do not suggest answer in Swift 4 and Xcode 9

Comment: use different cell identifier for each cell.

Answer (score 4):

You can try another approach: change the height of cells instead of insert / delete.

Change number of cells to always return all items:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        guard let sectionEnum = Sections(rawValue: section) else { return 0 }

        return sectionEnum.getRows(forExpanded: true).count
    }
```

Set height of 'hidden' items to 0:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    guard let sectionEnum = Sections(rawValue: indexPath.section) else { return 0 }

    let isExpanded = expandedSectionData[indexPath.section]
    if (!isExpanded) {
        let object = sectionEnum.getRows(forExpanded: true)[indexPath.row]
        if (!sectionEnum.getRows(forExpanded: false).contains(object)) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight
}
```

Set cell to clip subviews to its bounds:

```
       override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
           ....
           cell.clipsToBounds = true;
           return cell
        }
```

And change updating code to (remove tableView.reloadSections, change indexPath):

```
    func didBeginEditing(textField: UITextField, cell: UITableViewCell) {
        guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell), let section = Sections(rawValue: indexPath.section) else { return }
        if indexPath.row == 7 && !expandedSectionData[indexPath.section] {
            expandedSectionData[indexPath.section] = true
            tableView.beginUpdates()
            tableView.endUpdates()
            tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: UITableViewScrollPosition.none, animated: true)
            textField.becomeFirstResponder()
        }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to make textfield as first responder again, after reloading section text field no longer remains first responder.

You might need to change something like -

```
func didBeginEditing(textField: UITextField, cell: UITableViewCell) {
    guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) else { return }

    if indexPath.row == 2 && !expandedSectionData[indexPath.section] {
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        expandedSectionData[indexPath.section] = true
        tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: indexPath.section), with: .automatic)
        tableView.endUpdates()

        // after tableview is reloaded, get cell again
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 2, section: indexPath.section)) as? TestCell
        cell?.textField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

I have tried running this, kind of looks fine to me.

Comment: This seems to work to make the tapped (3rd) textfield, the first responder. However, if you try expanding for 3rd section and select other textfields, in couple of tries and manual scrolling, the issue still occurs. TL;DR This is not working.

Comment: so its related to setting the proper first responder, you know the root cause, now I believe you can fix?

Comment: I believe its not related to making the proper textfield the first responder. How do I know this? -> After adding the cells, if you select later cell's textfield, the textfield becomes the first responder but table view will still scroll such that it hides the responding textfield. So the problem is still there.

Comment: you need to take care of keyboard space using UIKeyboardWillShow & UIKeyboardWillHide Notifications

Answer (score 2):

This issue has to do with your use of [self-sizing tableview cells](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithSelf-SizingTableViewCells.html).  To fix the issue, comment out these two lines in your viewDidLoad and consider defining the height of your cells with tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:.

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
```

Since the self-sizing tableview documentation states,

> To define the cell’s height, you need an unbroken chain of constraints
>   and views (with defined heights) to fill the area between the content
>   view’s top edge and its bottom edge

I also tried changing the bottomMargin = textField.bottom constraint from priority 750 to 1000, but this did not fix the issue.